# Is it normal for air to be leaking from where the drain hose connects to the central A/C unit?

Tags: hvac, furnace, central-air

I'm trying to determine if I have a leak around my central AC unit. Basically when the unit is on, I feel cool air blowing outside the "furnace plenum" as I believe its called.

If you look at this picture, I think the air is coming from where the drain hose connects to the unit.

[image]

So my questions are:

```
1) Is this normal for air to be blowing out here

2) If not, is there a way I can seal it better?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That picture is kind of unclear but it certainly looks to me as if the drain (and maybe the whole a/c) was added as a retrofit to a furnace - the hole is uneven looking to me - sloppy.  I have something similar myself, in fact.

In answer:

1) No, it's not normal - it' a waste.  Air exchangers that are built to do both jobs do not have these kinds of gaps.

2) Yes - cut a piece of plastic to fit over the hole as much as possible.  Seal in place using METAL tape (not duct tape), closing up all the remaining gaps.

Comment: Shouldn't a gas line to a furnace be a solid line and not flexible? Thought that was a big no-no.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went ahead and sealed it off with some duck tape (I have to get some real HVAC tape). And no actually its not a retrofit, it was installed with the house which is only 8 years old. Thanks

Comment: @Mario - as I understand it, no - flexible gas lines are perfectly legal in many districts.